# How can I use from Navigation with EventBus without any clickListener - android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I am using from EventBus in my project, how can I use from `Navigation` like bellow:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun subLogged(valuesLoginBus: ValuesLoginBus) {
     Navigation.findNavController(view <----- ????).navigate(R.id.action_logget)
}
```

I don't have any `view` in `subLogged`.

**NOTICE:**  I have a dialog fragment login that when user logged it and when I get result from `API` I call `subLogged` in base fragment and redirect user to another fragment, but I don't have any `view` and `clickListener`

Comment: You can navigate to a destination with another methods regardless to a specific `View`, look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate)

Comment: So you are using navigation. What else are you using - are you using view models or some sort of mvp or mvc? I think the answer to your question is not possible without understanding big picture. In mvvm, if @subscribe is part of viewmodel, you could expose and observe livedata one-time-event and react to it when view lifecycle is ready.